# How to logging login and logout in Spring Security 4?

Tags: spring, spring-security

At most want to know what is the reason of login failed!

That is the code:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/assets/**",
                         "/user/register/**",
                         "/login/**",
                         "/page-register.html",
                         "/page-login.html").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .successForwardUrl("/index.html")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
            .loginPage("/page-login.html")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .and()
        .csrf().disable();  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By default your spring Application has something called a `ApplicationEventPublisher`, and Spring security sends `AbstractAuthenticationEvent` through this event mechnism, so all you have to do is listen. This is rather simple, you just need a component which implements `ApplicationListener`, like this:

```
@Component
public class SecurityEventListener implements ApplicationListener<AbstractAuthenticationEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(AbstractAuthenticationEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
    }
}
```

If you are using Spring 4.2 or newer, you don't need to implement the interface, just annotate the method with `@EventListener`. You can read more about listeners [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2)

When login fails, the event will extend `AbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent`, and contain the exception which was thrown. You can check the events source property to see what the user entered in the login form, and which IP he connected from.

Comment: This is great and works fine. But at least using oAuth this event is fired multiple times and may not be the best fit for logging logins.